# a lot of GREEN Color at YUV420p --> RGB in OpenGL 2.0 Shader on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ffmpeg, yuv

I want to make a movie player for iOS using ffmpeg and OpenGL ES 2.0
but I have some problem. Output RGB image has a lot of GREEN color.
This is code and images

- 480x320 width & height:
- 512x512 Texture width & height

I got a YUV420p row data from ffmpeg AVFrame.

```
    for (int i = 0, nDataLen = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        int nShift = (i == 0) ? 0 : 1;
        uint8_t *pYUVData = (uint8_t *)_frame->data[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < (mHeight >> nShift); j++) {
            memcpy(&pData->pOutBuffer[nDataLen], pYUVData, (mWidth >> nShift));
            pYUVData += _frame->linesize[i];
            nDataLen += (mWidth >> nShift);
        }
    }
```

and prepare texture for Y, U & V channel.

```
//: U Texture
    if (sampler1Texture) glDeleteTextures(1, &sampler1Texture);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glGenTextures(1, &sampler1Texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sampler1Texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // This is necessary for non-power-of-two textures
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                 0, 
                 GL_LUMINANCE, 
                 texW / 2, 
                 texH / 2, 
                 0, 
                 GL_LUMINANCE, 
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                 NULL);

    //: V Texture
    if (sampler2Texture) glDeleteTextures(1, &sampler2Texture);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    glGenTextures(1, &sampler2Texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sampler2Texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // This is necessary for non-power-of-two textures
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                 0, 
                 GL_LUMINANCE, 
                 texW / 2, 
                 texH / 2, 
                 0, 
                 GL_LUMINANCE,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                 NULL);

    //: Y Texture
    if (sampler0Texture) glDeleteTextures(1, &sampler0Texture);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glGenTextures(1, &sampler0Texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sampler0Texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // This is necessary for non-power-of-two textures
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                 0, 
                 GL_LUMINANCE, 
                 texW, 
                 texH, 
                 0, 
                 GL_LUMINANCE,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                 NULL);
```

Rendering part is below.

```
int _idxU = mFrameW * mFrameH;
int _idxV = _idxU + (_idxU / 4);

// U data
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sampler1Texture);
glUniform1i(sampler1Uniform, 1);

glTexSubImage2D(
                GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                mFrameW / 2,            // source width
                mFrameH / 2,            // source height
                GL_LUMINANCE,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                &_frameData[_idxU]);

// V data
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sampler2Texture);
glUniform1i(sampler2Texture, 2);

glTexSubImage2D(
                GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                mFrameW / 2,            // source width
                mFrameH / 2,            // source height
                GL_LUMINANCE,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                &_frameData[_idxV]);

// Y data
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sampler0Texture);
glUniform1i(sampler0Uniform, 0);

glTexSubImage2D(
                GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                mFrameW,            // source width
                mFrameH,            // source height
                GL_LUMINANCE,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                _frameData);
```

Vertex Shader & Fragment Shader is below.

```
attribute vec4 Position;
attribute vec2 TexCoordIn;

varying vec2 TexCoordOut;
varying vec2 TexCoordOut_UV;

uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 Modelview;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = Projection * Modelview * Position;
    TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn;
}



uniform sampler2D sampler0; // Y Texture Sampler
uniform sampler2D sampler1; // U Texture Sampler
uniform sampler2D sampler2; // V Texture Sampler

varying highp vec2 TexCoordOut;

void main()
{
    highp float y = texture2D(sampler0, TexCoordOut).r;
    highp float u = texture2D(sampler2, TexCoordOut).r - 0.5;
    highp float v = texture2D(sampler1, TexCoordOut).r - 0.5;

    //y = 0.0;
    //u = 0.0;
    //v = 0.0;

    highp float r = y + 1.13983 * v;
    highp float g = y - 0.39465 * u - 0.58060 * v;
    highp float b = y + 2.03211 * u;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(r, g, b, 1.0);
}
```

Y Texture (Grayscale) is correct but U & V has a lot of Green Color.
So final RGB image (Y+U+V) has a lot of GREEN Color.
What's the problem?

Please help.
thanks.

Comment: What do you mean - "u & v has a lot of green color"? U and V doesn't have color. They are U and V. Green color in final image comes from your "float g" computation. Have you verified formulas in CPU? Try converting your YUV data to RGB to see if your formula is correct. Also - why are you reading float u from sampler2, but v from sampler1 ? Comments after sampler definition says sampler1 is u and sampler2 is v.

Comment: I know that U & V doesn't have a green color. but when I did that y = 0.0; & v = 0.0; then output screen has a lot of green color. and I got mistake you said. sampler1 is u, sampler2 is v. but result is same. hmm. I did try to convert YUV to RGB via sws_scale in ffmpeg function. result is good.but the problem is speed(or performance).

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution for the problem? I'm trying to do the exact same thing, but with no luck...

Answer (score 7):

Change `u` and `v` uniforms (vice versa) and you will have correct result.

So pixel shader (stays the same):

```
uniform sampler2D sampler0; // Y Texture Sampler
uniform sampler2D sampler1; // U Texture Sampler
uniform sampler2D sampler2; // V Texture Sampler

varying highp vec2 TexCoordOut;

void main()
{
    highp float y = texture2D(sampler0, TexCoordOut).r;
    highp float u = texture2D(sampler2, TexCoordOut).r - 0.5;
    highp float v = texture2D(sampler1, TexCoordOut).r - 0.5;

    highp float r = y + 1.13983 * v;
    highp float g = y - 0.39465 * u - 0.58060 * v;
    highp float b = y + 2.03211 * u;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(r, g, b, 1.0);
}
```

and rendering code:

```
// RENDERING

    int _idxU = mFrameW * mFrameH;
    int _idxV = _idxU + (_idxU / 4);

    // U data
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sampler1Texture);

    GLint sampler1Uniform = glGetUniformLocation(programStandard, "sampler2");

    glUniform1i(sampler1Uniform, 1);

    glTexSubImage2D(
                    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    mFrameW / 2,            // source width
                    mFrameH / 2,            // source height
                    GL_LUMINANCE,
                    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                    &_frameData[_idxU]);

    // V data
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sampler2Texture);

    GLint sampler2Uniform = glGetUniformLocation(programStandard, "sampler1");
    glUniform1i(sampler2Uniform, 2);

    glTexSubImage2D(
                    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    mFrameW / 2,            // source width
                    mFrameH / 2,            // source height
                    GL_LUMINANCE,
                    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                    &_frameData[_idxV]);

    // Y data
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sampler0Texture);

    GLint sampler0Uniform = glGetUniformLocation(programStandard, "sampler0");
    glUniform1i(sampler0Uniform, 0);

    glTexSubImage2D(
                    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    mFrameW,            // source width
                    mFrameH,            // source height
                    GL_LUMINANCE,
                    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                    _frameData);


    //draw RECT
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);

    //ATTRIB_TEXTUREPOSITON
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXTUREPOSITON, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureCoords);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXTUREPOSITON);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    free(_frameData);

    [(EAGLView *)self.view presentFramebuffer];
```

Conclusion: `u <-> v` uniforms.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS supports rgb_422 textures, Instead of using three luminance texture use one rgb_422 texture. http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/APPLE/rgb_422.txt.

EDIT:
Whoops YUV480p is different than YUV422. In this case you must convert the YUV Data to an RGB data before uploading as a texture due to its odd layout.