# iOS - Render a YUV420p image using a BiPlanar pixel format in OpenGL ES 2

Tags: ios, opengl-es, rgb, yuv

I am trying to render a yuv420p encoded video to an OpenGL ES2 texture using Swift 3 on an iPhone 6S with iOS 10.3.3.

Texture Setup:

```
    var formatType = kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange
    var lumaTexture: CVOpenGLESTexture?  
    var chromaTexture: CVOpenGLESTexture?  
    var mediapixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
    var ioSurfaceBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?

    media.videoSamplesBuffer = media.assetReaderOutput?.copyNextSampleBuffer()
    mediapixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(media.videoSamplesBuffer!)!
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(mediapixelBuffer!, .readOnly)

    let bufferWidth0: Int = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(mediapixelBuffer!, 0)
    let bufferWidth1: Int = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(mediapixelBuffer!, 1)
    let bufferHeight0: Int = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(mediapixelBuffer!, 0)
    let bufferHeight1: Int = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(mediapixelBuffer!, 1)
    let bytesPerRow0: Int = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(mediapixelBuffer!, 0)
    let bytesPerRow1: Int = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(mediapixelBuffer!, 1)

    let pixelBufferBaseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(mediapixelBuffer!)
    let pixelBufferPlaneAddress0 = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(mediapixelBuffer!, 0)
    let pixelBufferPlaneAddress1 = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(mediapixelBuffer!, 1)

    let ioBufferRet = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                          bufferWidth_,
                                          bufferHeight_,
                                          self.formatType,
                                          attr,
                                          &ioSurfaceBuffer)
    if ioBufferRet != 0 { print("error at `CVPixelBufferCreate`", ioBufferRet) }

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(ioSurfaceBuffer!, .readOnly)

    var copyBufferPlaneAddress0 = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(ioSurfaceBuffer!, 0)
    var copyBufferPlaneAddress1 = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(ioSurfaceBuffer!, 1)

    memcpy(copyBufferPlaneAddress0, pixelBufferPlaneAddress0, bufferHeight0 * bytesPerRow0/2) // Y
    memcpy(copyBufferPlaneAddress1, pixelBufferPlaneAddress1, bufferHeight1 * bytesPerRow1/2) // UV

    glActiveTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE0))
    if nil != ioSurfaceBuffer && nil != media.vidTexCachePtr {
      var cvRet = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                              media.vidTexCachePtr!,
                                                              ioSurfaceBuffer!,
                                                              nil,
                                                              GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D),
                                                              GLint(GL_RED_EXT),
                                                              GLsizei(bufferWidth0),
                                                              GLsizei(bufferHeight0),
                                                              GLenum(GL_RED_EXT),
                                                              GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE),
                                                              0,
                                                              &lumaTexture)
      if cvRet != 0 { print("0 error at `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage`", cvRet) }
    }
    if nil != lumaTexture {
      glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(lumaTexture!), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(lumaTexture!))
    }
    glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER), GL_LINEAR)
    glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S), GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T), GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)

    glActiveTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE1))
    if nil != ioSurfaceBuffer && nil != media.vidTexCachePtr {
      var cvRet = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                           media.vidTexCachePtr!,
                                                           ioSurfaceBuffer!,
                                                           nil,
                                                           GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D),
                                                           GLint(GL_RG_EXT),
                                                           GLsizei(bufferWidth1),
                                                           GLsizei(bufferHeight1),
                                                           GLenum(GL_RG_EXT),
                                                           GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE),
                                                           1,
                                                           &chromaTexture)
      if cvRet != 0 { print("1 error at `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage`", cvRet) }
    }
    if nil != chromaTexture {
      glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(chromaTexture!), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(chromaTexture!))
    }
    glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER), GL_LINEAR)
    glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S), GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T), GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(mediapixelBuffer!, .readOnly)
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(ioSurfaceBuffer!, .readOnly)
```

Fragment Shader:

```
    #version 100
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec2 vUV;
    uniform sampler2D SamplerY;
    uniform sampler2D SamplerUV;

    void main() {

        mediump vec3 yuv;
        lowp vec3 rgb;

        yuv.x = texture2D(SamplerY, vUV).r;
        yuv.yz = texture2D(SamplerUV, vUV).rg - vec2(0.5, 0.5);

        // Using BT.709 which is the standard for HDTV
        rgb = mat3(      1,       1,      1,
                         0, -.18732, 1.8556,
                   1.57481, -.46813,      0) * yuv;

        gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, 1);
    }
```

The separate luminance texture looks right and but the separate Chroma texture seems to only have the Cr channel. I know that because the video is 4:2:0 the second chroma channel is empty and so maybe I shouldn't "see" the Cb channel, but the final result (which should be colorbar colors) looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byQYD.png).
It is missing the red. (I assume this is because the output is BGRA. If it were RGBA the blue would be missing). How do I get the red back?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170594/a-lot-of-green-color-at-yuv420p-rgb-in-opengl-2-0-shader-on-ios) describes a similar issue to the one I am experiencing. But the solution employs 3 planes (Y, U, and V separately) while I am trying to achieve this with 2 planes (Y, and UV). I tried using `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar` format type to get access to 3 planes, but then `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` fails to create an IOSurface. I've also tried a few different YUV->RGB shader equations and looked into using ffmpeg to supply the CVPixelBuffer, but I can't get it to build for my iPhone architecture (arm64). Thank you in advance and any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the `SamplerUV` texture was not actually being sent to the shader. (But it was viewable in the GPU captured frame, which was misleading). I assumed (incorrectly) that because the `SamplerY` was automatically sent to the shader, that the second texture, `SamplerUV`, would be as well. So the result I was seeing before was the luma texture being used for both Y and UV textures.

The missing lines that fixed the issue:

```
var SamplerY: GLint = 0
var SamplerUV: GLint = 1

SamplerY = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "SamplerY")
SamplerUV = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "SamplerUV")

glUniform1i(SamplerY, 0)
glUniform1i(SamplerUV, 1)
```